# Detect Outside App Opening

Tags: ios

I don't have much coding experience and haven't found any other good answers to this problem.

I want to create an app that will detect an outside app opening and notify the user.

How do I send a notification when another app is opened?

Comment: I hope you can’t. You are supposed to be sandboxed. If you find a way, I hope your app stays off my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect this, **iOS doesn't allow it** by using public API. Your app can't get such kind of information. So, don't even try. Even if you find a way (which is probably impossible), Apple won't let you release that app to AppStore.